# Parsing Just SIP Custom Header Values

Tags: sip, voip

> I want to parse **JUST** SIP Custom Headers [ or call attached data ] not
>   other  header fields.

As I see some guys use "X-" to distinguish those headers from standard headers.
But that is just convention.

In some systems , attached-data [ custom-headers ] are put into just after "Content-Length: " header but some put it after "Contact: " header.

I really can not find a generic AND elegant way, **just** to parse custom headers.

The only bad solution is create a Look-Up Table which contains all standard sip headers names and if header name is not in that list, parse that header which is **ugly**...

**Any suggestion  for more elegant solution ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to accomplish, but since servers/clients/proxy can inject any header they want, your only solution really is to have a white-list of valid header names. The major down-side is you have to take care of any new RFCs that define new "official" headers.

Depending on the use-case, you might want to just go for headers starting with `X-`. As you said, it's just a convention, but it's one that in wide use, IIRC.